# Escape ampersand while executing the script

Tags: wpf, powershell

I am trying to execute the PowerShell from WPF by pointing to the `powershell.exe` path. I have the following code

The error I am getting is

> The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.

```
string PSPath = string.Concat(Environment.SystemDirectory, "\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe");
string ScriptPath = string.Concat(PSPath, " -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ");
string CommandPath = string.Concat("\"& {&'", regex[0].ToString(), "'", regex[1].ToString(), "}\"");
ScriptPath = string.Concat(ScriptPath, CommandPath);
using (Process p = new Process())
{
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = PSPath;
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = ScriptPath;
    p.Start();
    string error = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
}
```

My script looks as follows:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "& {&'C:\TestPS\Testps1' -Arg1 -Arg2}"
```

which is executing fine when I directly copy paste into PowerShell, but not from the WPF application.

Comment: What's wrong with `-Command "C:\TestPS\Test.ps1 -Arg1 -Arg2"`?

Comment: Any update please I tried in several ways but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the way you are calling the ps1, it seems like you want to execute the ps1 simply only. Then don't use "**&**".

Call the script directly like :

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "C:\TestPS\Test.ps1 -Arg1 -Arg2"
```